# .attr('checked', 'checked') doesn't not work as intended

Tags: jquery, attr, checked

I have this code, which isn't working.

```
    .on("click","span.name", function selectThisName(e) {
        if (e.altKey) {
            username = jQ(this).text();
            if (username != 'None') {
                jQ("span.name:contains('" + username + "')").closest('.namedesign').prev().prev().attr('checked', 'checked');
                e.preventDefault();
                updateCheckedCount();
            }
        }
    }
```

It used to work but now it doesn't. It's supposed to check all boxes next to the posting field faster if I altclick on the same three or four spammer names.

However, I also have this code, which magially works. It focuses on unique user identification; the element itself includes the identification, unlike the username, which is "text-based". This is the site's code: http://puu.sh/9wxbw/03cb74487e.png

```
    .on("click","span.ident", function selectThisID(e) {
        if (e.altKey) {
            identification= "id_" + jQ(this).text();
                jQ("span." + identification).closest('.namedesign').prev().prev().attr('checked', 'checked');
                e.preventDefault();
                updateCheckedCount();
        }
    })
```

In this case, I would like to altclick on the name "heartbreaker" to check all of their accounts posts, but it isn't working. If I altclick on the ID, however, it works.

Why do I need this?
Well, sometimes I have to select names instead of the identifications. IDs are IP based (and they always change, otherwise people couldn't spam), while names aren't,  a lot of user accounts have been hijacked.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: May be you can post more code of your script? There is a missing closing parenthesis at the end of the first event handler but it's probably due to copy-past. I tried to recreate your situation in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3swJ/) - both handlers works fine

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `.attr('checked', 'cheked')` use `.prop('checked', true)`

[`$().prop()` documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Example: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/tiqavu/1/)

EDIT:

You can set `checked` property without jQuery:

```
$('input:checkbox').each(function(){
    //Get your input of type checkbox and set his property `checked` to boolean value:
    //Note: this is <input type='checkbox'>
    var isChecked = this.checked;
    this.checked = !isChecked;
    //Or using jQuery variable:
    $(this)[0].checked = true;
});
```

Comment: They both should work. jQuery automatically translates `attr` to `prop` in cases like this.

Comment: He said it used to work, and he says the second block of code, which also uses `.attr`, still works. Why would it only fail for the first block?

Comment: @Barmar: Do you have any documentation for jQuery using `prop` when you call `attr`? They are used for different things, so arbitrary substituting one for the other would be very unpredictable.

Comment: @Epsil0neR It doesn't work, console returns this: http://puu.sh/9wz2Z/6d503c650d.png

Comment: @Barmar: As far as I see that only applies to attributes assigned a boolean value.

Comment: @user3746271, if you just copied, then you used unexisting function `prob`, so i renamed it to `.prop`

Comment: @Guffa It applies to boolean attributes, regardless of whether you actually assign a boolean value. See http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/PVK76/

Comment: take a look to jQuery 1.6.1 release notes (@Barmar url above) and you will see in table that `checked` doesnt work with `attr()` function, but works with `prop()` function.

Comment: From the above page: _It is still recommended that .prop() be used when setting these boolean attributes/properties, but your code will continue working in jQuery 1.6.1 even if these use cases are not switched to use the .prop() method._

Comment: @Epsil0neR I have a matchbox that shows me how many posts have been selected. Instead of saying "None selected" it reacts to the updated fix you suggested by saying "0 selected" but it still doesn't check the boxes. The IDs work fine.

Comment: The script is also using jQuery v@1.8.1.

Comment: @Barmar: You can change the attribute, and that will also change the property, if the element is untouched. Once the element leaves this initial state, changing the attribute no longer affects the property. The exact behaviour probably varies between browsers, but in Firefox you can set the attribute and remove the attribute, and after that the element leaves the intial state and setting the attribute does not check the checkbox any more: http://jsfiddle.net/PVK76/1/

Comment: `prop` is in no way the same as `attr` and period. You should forget about `attr('checked')` or `attr('disabled')` and **always** use `prop` instead.